# А на stackoverflow раньше были личные сообщения или нет?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, личный-ящик

Была ли личная почта раньше на stack overflow или нет?

Comment: Ну, личные сообщения, можно было отправлять друг другу, в рамках сайта или нет?

Comment: Никогда не было

Comment: Не было и нет (и слава богу)

Comment: @ПетровСидор , есть публичные комментарии, адресуемые конкретному участнику обсуждения. (Уведомление о новом комментарии появляется только у участника, который упомянут в тексте, после символа `@`, но доступен для чтения всем.

Comment: А еще можно в чате создавать личные комнаты для двух участников.

Comment: @Глеб, но в них могут зайти все желающие :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а я думал, что на хэшкоде были?

Comment: @Глеб, ну они не совсем личные. Приватные только модератор может создавать.

Comment: @insolor, а ты ж с хэшкода ещё?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, "давно здесь сидим"

Comment: @Qwertiy по сабжу - вроде не было. Хэшкод по сути клоном SO был, все примерно так же было.